# CompletableFuture, mutable objects and memory visibility

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.concurrent, java-memory-model, completable-future

I'm trying to understand how `CompletableFuture` in Java 8 interacts with the [Java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html). It seems to me that for programmer sanity, the following should ideally hold true:

1. Actions in the thread that completes a `CompletableFuture` *happen-before* any <strike>completions</strike> dependent stages are executed
2. Actions in the thread that <strike>registers a completion</strike> creates a dependent stage *happen-before* the <strike>completion</strike> dependent stage is executed

There's a note in [java.util.concurrent documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) saying that:

> Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a `Runnable` to an `Executor` *happen-before* its execution begins. Similarly for `Callable`s submitted to an `ExecutorService`.

Which would suggest that the first property is true, as long as the thread that completes the future executes the <strike>completion</strike> dependent stage or submits it to an `Executor`. On the other hand, after reading [CompletableFuture documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) I'm not so sure about that:

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current `CompletableFuture`, or by any other caller of a completion method.

Which brings me to my questions:

1. Are the two hypothetical properties above true or not?
2. Is there any specific documentation anywhere about the presence or lack of memory visibility guarantees when working with `CompletableFuture`?

---

**Addendum:**

In the way of a concrete example, consider this code:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("foo");

CompletableFuture<List<String>> future =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
            list2.addAll(list1);
            return list2;
        });
```

Is it guaranteed that adding `"foo"` to `list1` is visible to the lambda function? Is it guaranteed that adding `list1` to `list2` is visible to the dependent stages of `future`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "thread that registers a completion"

Comment: @Misha: the OP obviously means a *completion action* or a dependent stage.

Comment: @Holger if he means completion action, then the two questions are the same.  It's more plausible that he means dependent stage.

Comment: @Misha: I meant “completion action” in the sense of “action to be performed on completion”, i.e. as submitted via `thenRun`. I admit that this is ambiguous, so, since all submitting methods also create a dependent stage, the term “dependent stage” should be preferred here.

Comment: @Misha @Holger Sorry for any ambiguity. By "a completion" I meant the function passed to `thenRun` etc. Are "creating a dependent stage" and "executing a dependent stage" the best terms here?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the terms and add a code example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, both of your hypotheses are true. The reason is, that all of the `*Async()` methods in `CompletableFuture` will use a `java.util.concurrent.Executor` to make the asynchronous call. If you don't provide one, this will either be the [common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) or an Executor that creates a [new thread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#CompletableFuture.ThreadPerTaskExecutor) for each task (in case you restrict the size of the common pool to 0 or 1) or a user-provided Executor.
   As you already found out, the [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executor.java?av=f) of the `Executor` says:

   > Actions in a thread prior to submitting a Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread.

   So in your example, it is guaranteed that `"foo"` is part of `list1` in your lambda and that `list2` is visible in subsequent stages.
2. This is basically covered by the documentation of `Executor`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I'm struggling to understand is that, for example regarding 2, if the thread that completes the future is different from the thread that creates the dependent stage, what establishes the _happens-before_ relation between actions in the thread that creates the dependent stage and the execution of the dependent stage? Wouldn't the _happens-before_ relation guaranteed by `Executor` only guarantee the relation between actions in the thread that completes the future and the execution of the dependent stage?

Comment: @AapoLaitinen The handover between two threads will always go through an `Executor`. So there is by definition a *happens-before* relationship. Completing the Future has the semantics of `Future#get()` which does also establish a *happens-before* relationship.