# Visibility guarantee with CompletableFuture's thenAccept

Tags: java, completable-future, java-memory-model, memory-visibility

I'm trying to understand if there are any visibility-guarantees provided by `CompletableFuture`.

Suppose I've a class called `SampleClass` which is something like the following:

```
public class SampleClass {
    private String member1;
    private String member2;
    // getters, setters and constructor;
}
```

And I do something like this:

```java
SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();

CompletableFuture<Void> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello")
        .thenAccept(sampleClass::setMember1);

CompletableFuture<Void> cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> " World")
        .thenAccept(sampleClass::setMember2);

cf1.join();
cf2.join();

// sout(sampleClass);
```

Now, I want to understand that in the `sout` statement, can there be a case when one or both the members is/are not initialized?

Basically is there any visibility-guarantee that's provided by `CompletableFuture` in here? (I'm under the impression that there's no such guarantee provided by `CompletableFuture` and the above code is broken.)

I've already gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427972/completablefuture-mutable-objects-and-memory-visibility) but I think it's not what I need.

Comment: `join()` is a convenience alternative to `get()`. And `Future.get()` has been addressed in [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility). It would be nice, for sure, if they expanded this part for Java 8 features. But I still consider its current form sufficient for assuming the right memory visibility. With one caveat, there must be no other completion. Since anyone can call `complete` on a `CompletableFuture`, such call would void any guarantees about any completion, as you don’t know which won.

Comment: Thanks @Holger for the comment. I got what you're hinting at. So `Future.get()` ensures *happen-before*  any action subsequent to `Future.get()`, so the call to `cf2.join()` should see the updated value of `sampleClass`. Is my understanding correct? And this visibility-guarantee won't be there if from somewhere, we're calling `CompletableFuture.complete()`, right?

Comment: Exactly. In case of multiple completion attempts, there will still be a *happens-before* relationship between the completion which “won” and the actions after `join()`, however, you’d need a safe way to determine which completion it was. For the typical case of evaluating functions which produce a result, it is safe to use the value returned by `join()`, as it is the result of the successful completion. But this doesn’t work for a side-effect like `setMember2`. The same applies to `CompletableFuture.anyOf(c1, c2).join()`; it would not give you any guarantees.

Comment: @Holger thanks a lot for this great explanation! This was really helpful.